# How to map a key to a sequence of key and combo, including that key?

Tags: x11, keyboard-shortcuts, xdotool

I tried to use `dxhd` with `xdotool` to prepend each key with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>, then type that key, and hit another key, like so

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

# @{a-z}
xdotool key ctrl+g
xdotool type {a-z}
sleep 1
xdotool key Tab
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is when I type any character, `a` for example, it will act as if I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>, then type an `a`, and wait for 1 second, and then hit <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

The problem is when I try to type `a`, it would actually send <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>, then an `a`, which would trigger another sequence recursively (another <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> -> `a` -> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> -> `a` -> ...).

Is there a correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There doesn't appear to be a native way to avoid recursion using `dxhd`, but it can be done with [`sxhkd`](https://github.com/baskerville/sxhkd) using the following configuration:

```
@{a-z}
    pkill -USR2 -x sxhkd; xdotool key ctrl+g key {a-z} sleep 1 key Tab; pkill -USR2 -x sxhkd
```

The first and last commands send `sxhkd` the `SIGUSR2` signal, which [toggles the grab state of all its bindings](https://github.com/baskerville/sxhkd/blob/master/doc/sxhkd.1.asciidoc#behavior). This allows us to use the bound key in between without causing recursion.

(The `xdotool` command has also been compressed into one line using its built-in [command chaining](https://github.com/jordansissel/xdotool/blob/master/xdotool.pod#COMMAND-CHAINING), just to make the line shorter; the original commands separated by `;` would also work. Unfortunately, `sxhkd` does not support multi-line commands.)

Comment: Thank you sir, I switched to sxhkd and that works.